# Kubernetes deployment KEDA autoscaling RabbitMq and monitoring system

Tags: spring, kubernetes, rabbitmq, keda

I have a spring app that I deploy it on k8s using docker desktop then i make it scale up and down based on the queue size (rabbitmq queue).

I wanna make simulation for a monitoring system and I want to create a spring app that returns:

- "YES" at 4pm
- "NO" rest of the day (this is just an example)

My original app sends request to the second app and based on the result I decide to scale up or not.

I want to now if this is even possible.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help